# Aligning preloader to center

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to align the preloader with class `preloader-align` to center of the `tab-containts`, But the problem is when i make   `left: 50%` nothing happens. Changes happen after increasing the percentage to `500%`  But it does not make it responsive.

Here is the code:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZBLzBe

```
.preloader-align{
  position:absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50% ;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;

}
.tab-containts{
  min-height: 500px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also add to `.preloader-align` below styles:

```
margin-left: -50px;
margin-top: -50px;
```

or use:

```
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

To center it perfectly.

Comment: Aye fixed, thanx :)

Answer (score 1):

`.tab-containts` needs a width, otherwise it's children don't know what `left:50%` means.

Edit: In order to get it truly centred, you need to account for the width of the preloader itself.

```
.preloader-align {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  //left: 50%;
  left: calc(50% - 32px);
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
}
.tab-containts {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 500px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vyxXVW)

Comment: Thanx but it's getting centered after setting the left to 40% Why so?

Comment: Well in order to get it truly centred, you need to account for the width of the preloader itself. So `left: calc(50% - 100px);` could achieve what you need.

Comment: Another thing you need to consider is that your preloader is 100px wide, but your circle is 64px wide

Answer (score 0):

Set your `.tab-containts` `width` to `100%` and then spinner or loader automatically get aligned to the center of parent div. At-present it aligns at center of parent div which doesn't have assigned width and that's why `left` properties didn't work, so if you add width then it works.

```
.tab-containts{
  min-height: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  width:100%;
}
```

Check this [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sw3yeork/)

Comment: Thanx but it's getting centered after setting the left to 40% Why so?

Comment: @IamNOOB did you check the link i.e. jsfiddle it is properly centered in middle of page.

Comment: Did u make any change in html?

Comment: @IamNOOB No I have not, just head and body tag which is not needed in jsfiddle.

Comment: i dont know why it's not working for me :( .. It's 10px right to the middle for me :(

Comment: @IamNOOB might be somewhere addition of padding.

Comment: @Whosoever down-voted could give me reason for that.